Lagrange's method for a quadratic form with a singular matrix

Can this quadratic form be brought to canonical form using Lagrange's method? $$x^2_2+x^2_4+2x_1x_3-2x_1x_4+2x_2x_4$$

I tried, but I failed. I found the matrix of this quadratic form, and it's singular. Does this affect the Lagrange method? I wrote $(x_2+x_4)^2+2x_1(x_3-x_4)$. After that, I tried various substitutions, and nothing worked. Maybe my whole approach is incorrect. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

The matrix is useless, except that its singularity allows to predict that you will need less than 4 squares. And why try "various substitutions" instead of continue to apply  Lagrange's algorithm? Please review it and then report your attempt. But before that, correct the minor sign mistake in your "$(x_2+x_4)^2-2x_1(x_3+x_4)$".

@AnneBauval Well, it took me a very long time to figure out to write $(x_2+x_4)^2+(x_1+x_3-x_4)^2-(x_3-x_4)^2-x_1^2.$ Honestly, I simply apply a series of substitutions in succession. I'm not entirely clear on the Lagrange's algorithm

Lagrange's method (called in France réduction de Gauss) provides a direct answer:
$$\begin{align}x^2_2+x^2_4+2x_1x_3-2x_1x_4+2x_2x_4&=(x_2+x_4)^2+2x_1(x_3-x_4)\\
&=(x_2+x_4)^2+\frac{(x_1+(x_3-x_4))^2-(x_1-(x_3-x_4))^2}2\\
&=(x_2+x_4)^2+\left(\frac{x_1+x_3-x_4}{\sqrt2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{x_1-x_3+x_4}{\sqrt2}\right)^2\\
\end{align}$$

After that, I wrote $(x_2+x_4)^2+(x_1+x_3-x_4)^2-(x_3-x_4)^2-x_1^2.$ I made the following substitution $y_4^2+(y_1+y_3)^2-y_3^2-y_1^2$ , I obtained $y_4^2+2y_1 y_3$ and then made the last substitution $y_1=z_1-z_2, y_3=z_1+z_2, y_4=z_3$. I finally obtained the quadratic form in its canonical form! $z_3^2+2(z_1-z_2)(z_1+z_2)=2z_1^2-2z_2^2+z_3^2.$
Next, I expressed $z$ in terms of $x$ and obtained the following transformation matrix: $ \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
    -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} $
Checked it, and everything matched up:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\
    -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 1  \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
    -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

You succeeded but seemingly by chance after an erratic sequence of substitutions. Better learn and apply directly Lagrange's algorithm. This  is the aim of such a training exercise.

@AnneBauval Thank you, I will try to understand this algorithm
